# UICollectionViewCell with UITextView poor scrolling performance (cells don't dequeue)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` for which cell heights can vary, while the width is full-width (I'm not using a `UITableView` because I'll need a different layout for iPad in the near future).

Straight to the point first: the weird thing is that dequeueing doesn't really ... dequeue. Cells never really get reused: if there are 40 items, 40 cells are getting initialised, and only then are they reused. I added a `print("initialising cell")` call in the cell's `init` method, and it prints as many times as there are cells.

I'm currently using auto-sizing cells, but I've also used the "keep a cell dummy property around to calculate the size" approach, and the outcome was the same. I even pre-calculated all the heights, before showing any data, basically not spending *any* time in `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` or `sizeForItemAt`.

- With self-sizing:

  - I have set the `estimatedSize` on the flow layout to `CGSize(width: view.width, height: 1)` - if I use a "real" average height, the `contentOffset` jumps around when scrolling;
  - I'm overriding `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting`, and here I'm calling `let newAttributes = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)`, then, before returning them, I'm setting `newAttributes.width = layoutAttributes.width`, since that's the `width` I actually need;
  - I have also tried not calling `super`, but `layoutIfNeeded` and `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, but the results were the same, even slightly worse

    - I also tried this, but by returning the cached sizes if they were already calculated, but the results were the same;
    - I also tried this, but by calling `super` as well, but the results were the same;
- Without self-sizing:

  - Calculate the heights in `sizeForItemAt` with my cell dummy;
  - Pre-calculate all the heights before displaying any data, and returning those in `sizeForItemAt`.
- Replacing the text view with a label:

  - if I don't use `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, it has the same problem;
  - if I do set it (no matter if in `init` or `layoutSubviews`), the problem is there at first, but goes away when reusing starts.

The text for the `UITextView` is 99% of the times under 5-6 rows, and I'm using it for the link detector.

I checked Time Profiler thoroughly, and there *are* spikes, but not where I'd expect them. It appears that on each spike, the most time is spent in `cellForItemAt`.

This is an average sample of the spikes:

- `UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer` has a whopping 76% Weight;

  - `layoutSubviews` has 37%;
  - `cellForItemAt` has 26%;

    - The `init` of the cell has 18.5%;

      - The `init` of my `UITextView` subclass has a whopping 9.2%, half of the whole cell's init;
    - My update cell method has 7.4%;
  - `_updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine` has 27.7%;
  - There's a `UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindowToWindow` at 10%;
- Some image assignment at 16%, but removing any image assigning code doesn't reduce the stutter whatsoever.

All the relevant code can be found here:  https://gist.github.com/rolandleth/ab5453b39a2cfe5c83119cb79ac3dc09

If any other info is missing/is required, please let me know.

Edit: The `CreateCell` (which has just an `imageView` and a `textView`) behaves exactly the same, so the number of subviews/constraints isn't a culprit here - I'm just eliminating any possibility I find.

Comment: "My cellForItemAt is terribly simple" And terribly wrong. The code you've shown wouldn't compile, and you are dequeuing without ever capturing the returned cell. Are you typing freehand? Don't. Copy and paste your real code right into the question, so that it's accurate.

Comment: Also please stop leaving out code. Don't say "my `cell.update` method is simple". _Show_ it. Show all the code on which the problem depends, including showing how you know you're not getting proper cell reuse. Provide enough info (perhaps in a reduced github project) so that _others can reproduce the issue_.

Comment: I was, indeed, typing freehand, and the code was an exemplification of what I have. I thought it'd be enough, my bad, and I'm sorry. I provided a gist of everything; sadly I can not provide a working project, as it's still ongoing and I can't really share much info. Thanks a lot for your continued assistance, Matt, greatly appreciated!